# php logout without issues

Tags: php, ajax, logout

i'm having some serious problems with my logout script (it crash 90% of the time)

> Important
>
> the script must delete the token from database and cookies if exist
>   (remember me isset) and then it should  unset `$_SESSION['user_id']`
>   and reloading the page at the same time

The problem is that sometimes it reloads the page before it deletes user session and keeps showing the member page until i reload again (i use one index file that contains login and member page separated with `if($person->is_logged())`)

for example : when i hit the logout button sometimes it deletes token from database without destroying user session or sometimes its the opposite but the main issue is that it crash and showing both member and login pages untill i reload again to show only the correct page

this is the ajax code

```
$("#signout").click(function () {
        var post_data = {
            'type': 'sign_out'
        }
        $.post('processing/core/connect.php', post_data, function (data) {
            window.location.reload();
        });
    });
```

then this is the php connect file :

```
if ($_POST['type'] == 'sign_out') {

    $person->logout();
}
```

And this is my logout function :

```
    private $cookie_user_id = "c_user";
    private $cookie_session_token = "xs";

    public function logout()
        {
            global $database;

            /* delete token from database */
            $database->query("DELETE FROM `users_sessions` WHERE `session_token` = '{$_COOKIE[$this->cookie_session_token]}' AND `user_id` = '{$_COOKIE[$this->cookie_user_id]}'");
            /* destroy the session */
            unset($_SESSION['user_id']);
            /* unset the cookies */
            setcookie($this->cookie_user_id, null, -1, '/');
            setcookie($this->cookie_session_token, null, -1, '/');
        }
```

Any good practices to force 100% the logout without any issues ?

Comment: For good practice starting points your query should be ``DELETE FROM `users_sessions` WHERE `session_token` = ? AND `user_id` = ?``. Always parameterize. You should use `$_SESSION`s as well, not `$_COOKIE`s

Comment: @user3783243 yeah, prepared statement, i was planning to do it after i fix this but thank you

Comment: Benefits of the cookies is they remember you when you come back to site, you should update cookies session from inactive to active on login, not delete on logout. deleting cookies means you don’t use benefits of cookies

Comment: @Dlk i'm deleting the cookie only after the logout operation

Comment: Well why using cookies then ? What is benefits of them ? Php sessions would be enough.

Comment: @Dlk the cookie always reinisialize the user session when the navigator is closed by comparing the token cookie with the one stored in database

Comment: @Dlk the session ends when the navigator is closed

Answer (score 1):

I think you must add some conditions to your code,
For the js code, you must get an answer from the page connect.php before reload the page because sometimes the php execution take more time then usuel so the page reload before the and of the process..
Also you must add conditions to the logout function, so the session can't be destroyed if the query failed for some reasons, and send an answer to js code if everything is good so the page can be reloaded if not show an error message and try to call the js again

Comment: It seems complicated but logical , i'm going to try this and get back to you as soon as possible

Comment: fixed mate, i found out that i used to call the windows location reload before $.post